# Problems with PageTitleProviders within in controller in cached action

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

in my extension i'm using a custom PageTitleProvider for my detail view. It only works when the page is not cached. So i clear the cache then the title will be the name of the record when i reload the page i get the page title. I can't set the action to uncached because of the loading times.

My PageTitleProvider looks like this:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\PageTitle\AbstractPageTitleProvider;

class CatalogPageTitleProvider extends AbstractPageTitleProvider
{
  /**
   * @param string $title
   */
  public function setTitle(string $title)
  {
    $this->title = (string)$title.' | '.$GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine[0]['title'] ;

  }


}
```

in the Controller i set the title like this:

```
$search = ['&npsp;', '&shy;' ];
$titleProvider = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(CatalogPageTitleProvider::class);
$titleProvider->setTitle( strip_tags(str_replace( $search, '',  $service->getName())));
```

Anyone know if there is something missing or is this a know bug?

Best regards 
die Knolle

Answer (score 1):

There was a bugfix about a year ago with the aim to remove the seperate caches for meta tags and page titles: https://git.higidi.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commit/44fe4992172ec0e18b28bc4a24c57a5c93b74121
From the bugfix description:

> By concept for frontend rendering the page title and meta tags are not
>   meant to be stored in page cache in order to allow non cachable
>   plugins to modify those.
>
> Currently both page title and meta tags are stored in separate cache
>   entries, which violates the concept above and unnecessarily tightly
>   couples those code parts to the TypoScriptFrontendController and
>   internal logic of it.
>
> This patch removes these caches.

This fix was introduced in v 9.5.8.

I reverted the script to version 9.5.7 in my project and the page titles are correct again: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/v9.5.7/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/PageTitle/PageTitleProviderManager.php

There must be a cleaner way to do this though, but I haven't found one yet.